# NSUndoManager : revert all the functionality of method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, undo, nsundomanager

I search lot about it but can't get more detail about what I want.

Is it possible to reverse all the functionality performed any method with the help of `NSUndoManager` class.

**For example** : suppose I am deleting any row from table view or remove any subview from its superview in that method. can I reverse that things with the help of `NSUndoManager`.

is `prepareWithInvocationTarget` method of `NSUndoManager` can helpful for that ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Generally with NSUndoManager, you have to implement the reverse action of anything you want to undo.  So NSUndoManager is only really helpful as a nice stack of reverse actions.  You still have to implement the reverse actions yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document has **all the answers**!

[**Introduction to Undo Architecture**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/UndoArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000010i)